# Notice: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager could not be converted to int

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entitymanager

I stumbled upon this error while trying to update an object and can't find any explanation. Here is my code:

Entity

```
    namespace Mnv\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class UtilitatiVariabile
 * @package Mnv\CoreBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="utilitati_variabile")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Mnv\CoreBundle\Entity\Repository\UtilitatiVariabileRepository")
 */
class UtilitatiVariabile {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=6, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $coeficient;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $kwh;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="original_kwh", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $originalKwh;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $mc;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="original_mc", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $originalMc;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $lei;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="original_lei", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $originalLei;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=6, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $leikw;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=6, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $leimc;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="suprafata_totala", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $suprafataTotala;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="total_col_mc", type="decimal", precision=20, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $totalColMc;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="total_col_kwh", type="decimal", precision=20, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $totalColKwh;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="total_col_lei", type="decimal", precision=20, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $totalColLei;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="total_col_total", type="decimal", precision=20, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $totalColTotal;

    /**
     * @var Utilitati
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Utilitati")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_utilitate", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $utilitate;

    /**
     * @var SesiuneUtilitati
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SesiuneUtilitati")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_sesiune", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $sesiuneUtilitati;
```

And i tried to update like this in my controller:

```
$variables = $this->getVariabileRepository()->find(1);
$variables->setKwh($kwh);
        .
        .
        .
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($variables);
        $em-flush();




   protected function getEntityManager()
        {
            return $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        }

    protected function getVariabileRepository()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('MnvCoreBundle:UtilitatiVariabile');
    }
```

I did the same with other entities and no problem, i don't know what is wrong with this one. I validated doctrine schema, nothing wrong there.

Answer (score 9):

I guess i am too tired to notice the freaking $em-flush typo :)))
Oh, boy! this is a weird one, i spent 30 min trying to figure out this error, never suspected a typo. Hope it saves someone's life some day :))

Comment: Ow man, had the exact same type. My IDE even highlighted it. Sleep is not only a joy but necessary apparently .